# Print Registered trademark symbol in text file using iron python script?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ironpython

How to print 'Registered trademark symbol' in text file using an IronPython script?

In my IronPython script I get data with a 'Registered trademark symbol' in the text.

Code:

```
for accRecvDetData in result.ResultArrayList:
    line = []
    line.append(str(accRecvDetData.NDCDescription))
```

NDCDescription data ex. `'CARDENE® I.V.'`

the error details:

```
('unknown', u'\xae', 0, 1, '')
```

Comment: Is that the full error message? What type is `accRecvDetData.NDCDescription` (what does `type(accRecvDetData.NDCDescription)` tell you it is)?

Comment: NDCDescription is string type

Answer (score 0):

Use `unicode` instead of `str` when dealing with strings which are likely to contain non-ASCII characters like ®.

```
for accRecvDetData in result.ResultArrayList:
    line= [unicode(accRecvDetData.NDCDescription)]
```

It also appears that you may mean to be creating an array containing all the NDCDescriptions. The code above doesn't do that, but this would:

```
lines = [unicode(accRecvDetData.NDCDescription) for accRecvDetData in result.ResultArrayList]
```